# Jailbroken iOS: NSTaskDidTerminateNotification fails to launch selector

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, nstask, nsnotification

I seem to have the same problem as here: [NSTask waitUntilExit hanging app on jailbroken iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139092/nstask-waituntilexit-hanging-app-on-jailbroken-ios)

Here's what I've got via NSNotification (like above), yet the `taskEnded:` alert(s) aren't coming up. The script is definitely run, as I can see it in the debugger.

```
-(IBAction) supported {
    stask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [stask setLaunchPath:@"/bin/bash"];
    NSString *script;
    script = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/apps.sh"];
    NSArray *sargs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:script, @"-txt", nil];
    [stask setArguments: sargs];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(taskEnded:)
                                                 name: NSTaskDidTerminateNotification
                                               object: nil]; 
    [stask launch];
}

- (void)taskEnded:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if (stask == [[notification object] terminationStatus]) {
        NSString *apps;
        apps = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/supported.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:apps]) {
            UIAlertView *supported = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Apps" message:apps delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok!" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [supported show];
            [supported release];
        } else {
            UIAlertView *supported = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Apps" message:@"Error generating list." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok!" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [supported show];
            [supported release];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Task failed."); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(taskEnded:)
                                                 name: NSTaskDidTerminateNotification
                                               object: stask];
```